# Suddenly stop copying SQLite Database from assets

Tags: android, sqlite

I am copying SQLite Database from assets folder to android app. I am using below mentioned code. And it was working fine and I am doing my code smoothly. Suddenly, it stopped copying database to android app.

```
public class PreCreateDB {

    public static void copyDB (Context context) {
        try {
            String destPath = "/data/data/"+ context.getPackageName()+ "/databases";
            File f = new File(destPath);
            if (!f.exists()) {
                f.mkdir();
                rawCopy(context.getAssets().open("dbname.db"), new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/dbname.db"));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void rawCopy(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException{

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

    }
}
```

I found db in Device File Explorer and I see the following lines in it (not whole tables). Kindly help

```
SQLite format 3   @                                                                   .�
   � �                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         W--ctableandroid_metadataandroid_metadataCREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   � �                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             en_IN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my code to the following one, now it's working.

```
public static void copyDB (Context context) throws IOException {

        try (SQLiteDatabase dbe = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.app.example/databases/dbname.db", null, 0)) {
            dbe.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.app.example/databases/dbname.db");
            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            int r;
            InputStream is = am.open("dbname.db");
            while ((r = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, r);
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }

    }
```